# How I can set the value of element of a fragment?

Tags: sapui5

This is my fragment,
The fragment not have a controller

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <Dialog
    title="Invio report via mail">
    <content>

        <FlexBox
            alignItems="Start"
            justifyContent="Center">
            <items>
             <TextArea id="idMailReport" value="themail.mail.it" rows="1" cols="50" /> 
            </items>
        </FlexBox>



    </content>
    <beginButton>
      <Button text="Ok" press="onDialogOkButton" />
    </beginButton>
    <endButton>
      <Button text="Close" press="onDialogCloseButton" />
    </endButton>
  </Dialog>


</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Ho I can set che value of TextArea element?

I try to set it from a controller where I call the fragment:

```
var dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "dialogFragment",
                "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
                this // associate controller with the fragment
          );
          this.getView().addDependent(dialogFrafment);
          dialogFrafment.open();
          this.byId("idMailReport").setValue("initial.mail.com");
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Access Elements from XML Fragment by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660161/how-to-access-elements-from-xml-fragment-by-id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it!

```
var dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
                this.getView().getController() // associate controller with the fragment            
          );
```

my problem is that i had set a name of a fragment: "dialogFragment"
Whitout it all work! ;)

Comment: `dialogFragment` was the *ID prefix* of the fragment, not the *name*. The reason why it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872515/5846045

Answer (score 6):

please try

`sap.ui.getCore().byId("idMailReport").setValue("initial.mail.com");`

it should work.

Here is the official [document](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b325518a2ae48ee91eb2dacda1d1420.html).

Comment: Hi bradipo, please do the following:var dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
                "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
                this // associate controller with the fragment
          );

Comment: :/    I see this article: http://goo.gl/rGKOoW
Here http://pastebin.com/Y2eif0xU I declare my fragment.
Here http://pastebin.com/5RVuchZv I create it and launch and test it

The fregment opens without problems, but when I test `console.log(sap.ui.getCore().byId("idMailReport"));` it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

A bit outdated, but might be useful for others. When you reuse your fragment inside a view, giving it unique id like:

```
    var dialogFrafment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
            "dialogFragment", // this is fragment's ID
            "appIntra.fragment.dialog",
            ...
      );
```

retrieving id of your nested control goes like:

```
this.byId(sap.ui.getCore().Fragment().createId("dialogFragment", "idMailReport"));
```

That way, your prepend fragment's id to your control's id.