# Cannot get a control in fragment dialog

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am facing the following issue. I have a Fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" >
    <Dialog title="Hints" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" contentWidth="60%">
        <content>
            <Table id="tblHintList" mode="SingleSelect" items="{HintList>/}" growing="true" growingThreshold="10" selectionChange="onGetSelectedHints">

            </Table>
        </content>         
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

In my controller I want to access the Table by its ID as follows:

`var table = this.getView().byId("tblHintList");`

This is not working even though I called `this.getView().addDependent(Fragment)` and data binding is working.

How can I access the controls defined in the Fragment?

Comment: Getting a control from a fragment depends on how you created your fragment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872515/5846045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you have to distinguish these [use cases](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b325518a2ae48ee91eb2dacda1d1420.html): The fragment is part of your view or not. You are instantiating your fragment with or without an ID.

In your case the fragment is not part of the view, as it is a dialog. In this case you would obtain your table control as follows:

```
var table = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tblHintList");
```

Assuming you are using an ID "myDialog" to instantiate the fragment as follows:

```
var dialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("myDialog", "my.package.HintListDialog");
```

then you obtain your table control as follows:

```
var table = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("myDialog", "tblHintList");
```

In general you should **not** assemble control IDs by yourself as suggested in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

`this.getView().byId()` is not working as your fragment has not been provided with an Id of the view while instantiating. So, let us suppose I have a Fragment: HelloDialog.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" >
   <Dialog>
        <content>
            <List id='myId'
            noDataText="No Products Found"
            title="Uraian"
            search="handleSearch"
            confirm="handleClose"
            close="handleClose"
            items="{
                path: 'list>/'
            }" >
                <StandardListItem
                    title="{list>Name}"
                    description="{list>ProductId}"
                    iconDensityAware="false"
                    iconInset="false"
                    type="Active" />
            </List>
        </content>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I will instantiate it with 2 different ways ( remember the Id of the list is :myId)

1. **Instantiate without any Id:** Code:

   oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("testbed.HelloDialog");
   oView.addDependent(oDialog);

Now, if you will check the DOM, the Id of the List will be just `myId`.
So, to fetch Id in these casem use: `sap.ui.getCore().byId('myId').`

2. **Instantiate with ID:** Code:

   `oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment('fragmentId', "testbed.HelloDialog");
   oView.addDependent(oDialog);`

Now, if you will check the DOM, the Id of the List will be : `fragmentId--myId`.

Here, again you can use `sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("fragmentId", "myId");`
; // Thanks to matbtt

Now, **what if I associated  ID of view to be used with my Fragment** ie :

```
     var oView = this.getView();
     var oDialog = oView.byId("helloDialog");
     // create dialog lazily
     if (!oDialog) {
        // create dialog via fragment factory
        oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "testbed.HelloDialog");
        oView.addDependent(oDialog);
     }
```

Id of List in DOM: `viewId--myId`

Now, I can use my `this.getView().byId()` as `this.getView().byId()` simply appends the view Id and then searched for the control.

P.S: You can use`this.byId()` rather than `this.getView().byId()` ( where this refers to the controller).