# How to get id of invisible element in fragment?

Tags: sapui5

I have a Dialog in fragment:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog title="{i18n>AddNewItem}" resizable="true" draggable="true">
        <content>
            <MessageStrip
                id="failMsg"
                visible="false"
                text="{i18n>SensorTypesCreateFail}"
                type="Error"
                showIcon="true"/>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

As in [UI5 doc](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8b325518a2ae48ee91eb2dacda1d1420)：

> Retrieving a control instance when the fragment is not part of a view:
>
> - When no fragment ID was given: myControl = sap.ui.getCore().byId("myControl")
> - When a fragment ID myFrag was given:  myControl = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId("myFrag", "myControl")

If there is no `visible="false"`, I can get this MessageStrip by `sap.ui.getCore().byId("failMsg")`.

But I found that with `visible="false"`, id of MessageStrip is `sap-ui-invisible-failMsg`, I failed to found proper API to get it.

Of course I can use `sap.ui.getCore().byId("sap-ui-invisible-failMsg")`, but I am not sure whether this ID will change after I deploy it to FLP, and as @schnoedel said in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660161/sapui5-xml-fragment-access-element-by-id):

> Beware that the prefixes like -- and --- used by the framework may change in the future. Thats why it's recommended to use the public api functions the framework supplies like byId() and createId().

So, is there any better way to get it?

---

Update:

Change my code from:

```
this[dialogName] = sap.ui.xmlfragment("namespace." + dialogName, this);
this.getView().addDependent(this[dialogName]);
```

To

```
this[dialogName] = sap.ui.xmlfragment(dialogName, "namespace." + dialogName, this);
this.getView().addDependent(this[dialogName]);
```

And now my id is `sap-ui-invisible-dialogName--failMsg`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve after getting the ID. If you just want to change a property you could do it without any ID via a Model.

For that you can assign a Model field (i.e. baseModel>/visable) to the visable property and once it should be changed you change the model and via two way binding it updates the control.
code to change a model:
this.getView().getModel("nameOfUrModel").setProperty("property", "value")

for more information about this just check the walkthrough tutorial on
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/

And if you for whatever reason really need the ID:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Fragment.html
here you find the command:
sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(sFragmentId, sId)
It should be able to return the Control your using

Hope that helps
Eric

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Fragment.js#L177  It seems ` sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(sFragmentId, sId)` equals to `sFragmentId + "--" + sId`, It did not work for id `sap-ui-invisible-failMsg`, since it is not `myFragmentId--failMsg`

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to the solution. After adding `dialogName` for the fragment ID in its creation, you just have to call the API ...:

```js
sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/Fragment"], Fragment => Fragment.byId(dialogName, "failMsg"));
```

... to get the control instance as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872515/5846045).

However, regardless whether you provided a fragment ID or not, you can easily ignore the [render prefix](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/ff9363ca25fced61c1a80427a3576c73c344fa48/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/RenderManager.js#L1207-L1222) `"sap-ui-invisible-"` at any time - Meaning that you could've also been able to get the control instance via `sap.ui.getCore().byId("failMsg")` instead of `sap.ui.getCore().byId("sap-ui-invisible-failMsg")` even if the control is invisible.