# Get Control ID Defined in XML Fragment

Tags: sapui5

I have a fragment having many input fields. I want to check the ID of the input field in which text was entered. When I do `oEvent.getSource().getId()`, 
I get `"someId-controlId"`. I am not sure what that `"someId"` is of. But after `"-"` is the `"controlId"` for sure. Could anyone advise how to separate the control ID from the output I am getting or how to extract control ID in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how the global ID is created [depends on how the fragment was created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872515/5846045). Moreover, this is how separators are **currently** used between the ID segments:

- Components append `"---"`
- Views append `"--"`
- Controls / elements append `"-"` (e.g. for cloned instances via aggregation binding)

Sample output:

```
"componentId---viewId--controlId-__clone0"
```

The number of separators, how they are inserted, or even which character is used to separate each segment might change in later versions. In fact, there is a warning in the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5da591c5a5a54740948acfe56b22fbc3) not to rely on the current syntax:

> Do **not** rely on the specific prefixing syntax because it may change at some point.

To make it worse, no errors are thrown when such a separator was indeed used in the `id` definition. Assuming the separator character might be included in the `id` definition makes extracting the right part from the global ID much harder and unpredictable.

In order to make each control distinguishable, a better approach would be to add [CustomData](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/addCustomData).

```
<Input change=".onChange">
  <customData>
    <core:CustomData key="is" value="A" />
  </customData>
</Input>
<Input change=".onChange">
  <customData>
    <core:CustomData key="is" value="B" />
  </customData>
</Input>
<Input change=".onChange">
  <customData>
    <core:CustomData key="is" value="C" />
  </customData>
</Input>
```

The custom data can be then retrieved in the Controller via the [API `data`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Element/methods/data):

```
onChange: function(oEvent) {
  const inputIsFrom = oEvent.getSource().data("is"); // returns: "A", "B", or "C"
  // ...
},
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it better now. I will use cust data. I read some blogs online and got even more confused earlier. Now I am clear.

Comment: @THI I just read that comment now. Honestly, I don't think much of blog posts as they're rarely maintained and sometimes even just incorrect. I'd suggest to stick with the [documentation](https://ui5.sap.com/) and, if encounting errors, [debugging the source code](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/14/debugging-fiori-and-ui5-materials/).