# How to access control from the popup fragment by ID

Tags: sapui5

I want my text area to be empty after I press <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

I have try this line `this.byId("id").setValue("")`

```js
onWorkInProgress: function (oEvent) {
  if (!this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog) {
    this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("WIPworklist", "com.sap.FinalAssestments.view.WorkInProgress", this);
    //this.byId("WIP").value = "";
    //this.byId("WIP").setValue();
    this.getView().addDependent(this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog);
  }
  var bindingPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
  this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog.bindElement(bindingPath);
  this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog.open();
},
        
//function when cancel button inside the fragments is triggered
onCancelApproval: function() {
  this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog.close();
},

//function when approval button inside the fragments is triggered
onWIPApproval: function() {
  this._oOnWorkInProgressDialog.close();
  var message = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("wipSuccess");
  MessageToast.show(message);
},
```

The text area will be in popup in the fragment. I am expecting the text area to be empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You almost have it, I think. Just put the 
`this.byId("WIP").setValue("")` line after the `if()` block. Since you are adding the fragment as a dependent of your view, `this.byId("WIP")` will find the control with id `"WIP"` every time you open the WIP fragment and set its value to blank.

You are likely not achieving it now because A. it is not yet a dependent of your view and B. it is only getting fired on the first go-around.

Comment: I was thinking of your solution, but following your solution, the text would be cleared when opening the popover.  In her request she wants to clear the text when pressing 'OK' :)

Comment: Is it not effectively the same thing for a dialog? I actually prefer to do it this way since I have always found it easier to centralize code on opening dialogs rather than on close.

Edit: Either way, ```this.byId()``` should work after initial addition as dependent is performed

Comment: It would only work if the fragment was loaded via `sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "com.sap.FinalAssestments.view.WorkInProgress", this);`. It has **nothing** to do with `addDependent` (which is mainly necessary to share the models of the view with the fragment). *Source: I just tried it.*

Comment: Ah - thanks for the correction @Marc. I suppose it is a "good practice" guideline that I always use (since model propagation is almost always needed) which I have conflated the benefits. My typical dialog open looks like this:


    const oView = this.getView();
 if (!this._CreditCardDialog) {   
            this._CreditCardDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "app.view.fragments.CreditCardDialog", this);
            oView.addDependent(this._CreditCardDialog);
        }
        // clear any models/fields necessary
        this._CreditCardDialog.open();
*sorry about formatting

Comment: Seems like good practice to me, but depending on your version you might want to switch. `sap.ui.xmlfragment` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will keep that in mind on newer projects

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate your fragment like this:

```js
sap.ui.xmlfragment("WIPworklist", "com.sap.FinalAssestments.view.WorkInProgress", this);
```

You can access its controls like this:

```js
Fragment.byId("WIPworklist", "WIP").setValue(""); // Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
```

Source: [How to Access Elements from XML Fragment by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660161/how-to-access-elements-from-xml-fragment-by-id)

---

**The better approach would be to use a view model.** The model should have a property `textAreaValue` or something like that.

Then bind that property to your TextArea (`<TextArea value="{view>/textAreaValue}" />`). If you change the value using code (e.g. `this.getView().getModel("view").setProperty("/textAreaValue", "")`), it will automatically show the new value in your popup.

And it works both ways: if a user changes the text, it will be automatically updated in the view model, so you can access the new value using `this.getView().getModel("view").getProperty("/textAreaValue");`.